# How should this sink drain be connected?

Tags: plumbing, sink

There was a blockage in the sink and I dismantled the pipes trying to fix it but cannot put it back together correctly. It appears the Waste drain pipe that leaves the house is too high and maybe the plumber used a special configuration of the pipes to make it work.

Can someone please sketch me a quick diagram of how I connect things back up?

[image: Here is photo of under the sink]

[image: Here is photo of all the parts that I need to reconnect correctly]

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Probably why the plugging occurred to begin with.  Since you have a flex hose it can all be hooked up and the sinks will drain since they are still higher than the waste pipe, but you're correct that it's not correct.

Comment: The exit point of the drain pipe on the left is too high for your arrangement to work.  Along with 4 or 5 other problems you have.  You can perhaps finesse the height issue if you use a setup similar to what longneck suggests, but you might be better off cutting into the wall to lower the drain's exit point.

Answer (score 10):

Your sink doesn't drain properly because the water has to go up hill to drain. The right way to fix this is to remove this elbow:

[image]

And then re-plumb it like this (but flipped horizontally):

[image]

You will probably have to replace the existing tailpieces to get enough clearance.

Comment: And whatever you do, DON'T forget the trap.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I would expect to see in a typical installation.

[image: Ideal case]

I would recommend getting rid of that flexible pipe and doing it right. Waste-side sink plumbing isn't too hard. Work from the sink connections back to the pipe in the wall.

The only thing I see here outside of my experience is the pipe in the wall is grey. PVC is usually white. Make sure you use the right couplings and glues to make the joint.

I have retained the street-tee you already have. You may need to replace it with a new street-tee and a coupling for the hose. I assume that hose is for the dishwasher. All standard parts, they probably even come in a kit.